# How to close a jquery dialog from inside the open function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I want to open this dot_card.php page in a dialog box.  I want to interrupt the the form submission to do some stuff and them do an ajax call.  After the form is submitted via ajax, I want to close the dialog box.  But the code below doesn't seem to close it.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
    $('<div><div id="addDotDiv"></div></div>').appendTo('body').dialog({
        modal: false,
        title: 'title',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        zIndex: 10000,
        autoOpen: true,
        minWidth: 650,
        resizable: false,
        position: { my: 'top+50', at: 'center', of: '#id-top' },
        open: function() {
            $('#addDotDiv').load('dot_card.php', '', function() {
                $('#create_dot_form').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    var actionUrl = $('#create_dot_form').attr('action');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: actionUrl,
                        data: $('#create_dot_form').serialize(),
                        success: function() {
                            $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        close: function() {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `this` is going to be the Ajax request. `$('#addDotDiv').closest('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that, and nothing seems to happen.  I don't even get any console errors.

Comment: The preventDefault code indeed does interrupt the form submission and the ajax call indeed does get made, but on success, the dialog doesn't close.